# Rails 3.2 form for one-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have the following models:

- User
- Apps
- Service
- Apis

A User has a list of Services he/she can access.

When creating an App I need to be able to add/remove services to it based on the Services a User can access. The same applies for editing an App.

We are using simple form.  The association method is great for displaying Services with a checkbox to add / remove from the App.

The problem we face is that Services have Apis and we need to display information related to the Apis under a Service.  A User still needs to be able to select a Service to add/remove from an App, as well as display information about it's Apis below.

It's seems the association method in simple form does not support the functionality we need to display information related to Apis in addition to being able to add/remove an Service from an App based on the User's list of Services he/she can access.

We have spent some time trying to figure out how to solve this problem e.g., nested forms, array parameters, simple form api, etc.

I would think there would be a Rails way to do this.

Comment: Use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your model with `has_many` and the `fields_for` method in your view.

Comment: This will display the records that exist in the relationship. I need a user to be able to select records based on a query regardless of whether the exist or not. A user should be able to add and remove from the list.

Comment: The answer is actually the Simple Form gem's association method. I just added an array of the specific instance to the association method.